# Multiplication of values in Jolt Transformation Spec

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I have input as shown below, If `timeMeasurementUnitCode="DAY"` then value I need to calculate as `value*24*60`, if `timeMeasurementUnitCode="HOUR"` then value `value*60`

I see there is one similar use case people are looking for, `the ticket is opened on Jul 17, 2019`: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/832

Issue [832](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/832) seems still open now

Input:

```
{
  "freightCharacteristics": {
    "transitDuration": {
      "timeMeasurementUnitCode": "DAY",
      "value": 6
    },
    "loadingDuration": {
      "timeMeasurementUnitCode": "HOUR",
      "value": 6
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output: Based on the constant provided in the input as `DAY` or `HOUR`, I need to multiple `no.of days*hours*minutes` to arrive at my requirement as shown below.

```
{
  "transitDurationInMinutes" : 8640,
  "loadingDurationInMinutes" : 360
}
```

]

As per the suggestion from @mattyb, I used divide function to achieve what want to achieve by multiplication, logic is updated as below.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "freightCharacteristics": {
        "transitDuration": {
          "timeMeasurementUnitCode": {
            "DAY": {
              "@(2,value)": "transitDurationInMinutes"
            },
            "*": {
              "@(2,value)": "transitDurationInMinutes"
            }
          }
        },
        "loadingDuration": {
          "timeMeasurementUnitCode": {
            "HOUR": {
              "@(2,value)": "loadingDurationInMinutes"
            },
            "*": {
              "@(2,value)": "loadingDurationInMinutes"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "transitDurationInMinutes": "=divide(@(1,transitDurationInMinutes),0.00069444444)",
      "loadingDurationInMinutes": "=divide(@(1,loadingDurationInMinutes),0.01666666666)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "transitDurationInMinutes": "=toInteger",
      "loadingDurationInMinutes": "=toInteger"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You likely need a `modify-overwrite-beta` spec rather than a shift spec, see examples here: http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#modify-mathFunctions

Comment: @mattyb Could you please specify which function from your link I can use for multiplication? I have done verified all this then only I put my question here

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a `multiply` function yet, so you'd have to use `divide` with a decimal, then possibly convert back to an integer: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be making `DAY` and `HOUR` literals object keys respectively in order to pick them conditionally within the next step such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "value": "@(1,timeMeasurementUnitCode).&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "DAY": {
        "val": "=divide(1,@(1,value))",// 1/6 will be used to simulate a multiplication
        "div": "=divide(1440,@(1,val))",
        "transitDurationInMinutes": "=toInteger(@(1,div))"// to eliminate decimal representation which ends with ".0"
      },
      "HOUR": {
        "val": "=divide(1,@(1,value))",
        "div": "=divide(60,@(1,val))",
        "loadingDurationInMinutes": "=toInteger(@(1,div))"
      }
    }
  },
  {// get rid of object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*Duration*": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]